# How to prevent a changelist(model) to be populated

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm new to Django and for a small project I need to open changelist of some models without any data. How we can prevent initial populating of some models?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `ChangeList` subclass.  For example the following code will open an empty changelist but if you will search for name then the list will be populated by the search results:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class MyChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(MyChangeList, self).get_queryset(request)
        if not request.GET.get('q', ''):
            queryset = queryset.none()
        return queryset

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    search_fields = ['name']

    def get_changelist1(self, request, **kwargs):
        return MyChangeList
```